# Input formula with string concatenation through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

No doubt the solution is probably right under my nose, but after spending hours messing with this I give up.  I have a workaround which is not acceptable. Here is the formula straight out of the spreadsheet:

```
="https://www.google.com/maps/?z=12&t=k&q="&D2&"'"&C2
```

Here is the VBA code for which I get errors whatever I seem to do with it.

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "="""https://www.google.com/maps/?z=12&t=k&q="""&D2&"" '""&C2"
```

I would surely appreciate it if someone could help.  I don't normally have too much difficulty with concatenation, but, this one has got me and there is no doubt some simple trick I am overlooking.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `&` string concatenation operator in Excel formulas can be used like this (without spaces), but be careful in VBA code; make sure to precede it with a space, otherwise `FooBar&` gets interpreted as a [type hint](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/2960/type-hints#t=201707141458476405156) for a `Long` identifier, as `42&` gets interpreted as a type hint for a `Long` literal.

Comment: I will take a look at that and keep that in mind.  Thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `.Formula` when dealing with A1 notation.

And only `""` on each end of the website string.

use this:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=""https://www.google.com/maps/?z=12&t=k&q=""&D2&""'""&C2"
```

Comment: That did it!  It seems to me that it can be unnecessarily difficult at times.  If they were able to send a man to the moon...  Thanks for saving a lot more time!!  Will vote it up as soon as I'm eligible...